# How to use material design in android studio

Tags: android, material-design

1. How to write xml code in Android Studio for interactive UI using Material Design
2. Which Material Design library to implement?

I tried implementing Material Design but failed, xml code, while running is not able to show material design.
Is there any specific way to write material design code in xml file

Comment: I just added an answer to your question. If you need further help, you can leave a comment below my answer If the answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you set up a new Android project using the default project [setup wizard](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project) that Android Studio offers.

1. Open Android Studio and click "Start a new Android Project"
2. Choose your project type. I'd recommend that you select the "Basic Activity (Material 3)" template. If you want the old Material2 Design, just use the template "Basic Activity".
3. Set a project name, project directory, and minimum SDK version.

Android Studio will create a new project for you, with everything you need in order to use Material Design Components. It automatically sets your

- dependencies (build.gradle)
- styles (styles.xml)
- XML namespaces

If you want to get Material Design to an existing project, have a look at the `build.gradle` and `styles.xml` files in your new project to see what you need to have Material Design in your existing project.